# how to know when the user cut when the call through dialogflow telephony

Tags: dialogflow-es

We have integrated the bot with dialogflow phone gateway. I want to know when the user cuts the call without saying quit or stop.

Is this possible?

Comment: See the documentation: https://dialogflow.com/docs/events/platform-events and https://dialogflow.com/docs/events/custom-events

Comment: But we are not using actions on google. So we do not enable it